# Unable to drop duplicates in index in python DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I am trying to drop duplicated index in multindexed python `pandas` `dataframe`

```
    import pandas as pd
    arrays=[['i1', 'i2', 'i3'], ['j1', 'j2', 'j3']]
    tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
    index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
    df=pd.DataFrame({'a':['b', 'c', 'd']}, index=index)
    df = df.groupby(df.index).first()
    print(df)
```

but duplicates in index have not been removed:

```
          a
(i1, j1)  b
(i2, j2)  c
(i3, j3)  d
```

How do I do that?

Expected output:

```
          a
(i1, j1)  b
(i2, j2)  c
```

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: Because in sample data is not duplicated MultiIndex

Comment: Actually, yes. I corrected input data and it worked